# Character Driver with Circular buffer

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning device driver programming and I have created a simple character driver where I am passing data from a user space app and storing it in a kernel space circular buffer, then reading this circular buffer again from another user space app.

I am using linux kernel version 3.3.6

My driver code is:

```
/* A simple character driver program to pass some data from user space and storing that on kernel circular buffer and reading back it on user space */

#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/vmalloc.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/major.h>
#include<linux/cdev.h>
#include<asm/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/device.h>
#include<linux/types.h>
#include<linux/kdev_t.h>
#include<linux/wait.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/circ_buf.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("C-DAC");
#define MAX_DEVICE 2
#define KERN_BUFF_SIZE 1
#define DRIVER_NAME "ass3q1" 

int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp);
ssize_t my_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *usr_buff, size_t count, loff_t *ppos);
ssize_t my_read(struct file *filp, char __user *usr_buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos);
int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp);
long my_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd,unsigned long arg);


/* DEFINE A DEVICE SPECIFIC DATA */
typedef struct privatedata1
{
    int minor_num;
    struct cdev mycdev;
    struct circ_buf KERN_BUFF;
    int KERN_SIZE;
//  char KERN_BUFF[KERN_BUFF_SIZE];
}my_privatedata;

my_privatedata devices[MAX_DEVICE];

/* DECLARE THE REQUIRED VARIABLES */
int major;
int minor=1;
dev_t device_num;

struct class *my_class;
struct device *my_device;

/* DEFINE THE FILE OPERATIONS STRUCTURE OF THE CHAR DRIVER */
struct file_operations my_fops={
    .owner      = THIS_MODULE,
    .open       = my_open,
    .write      = my_write,
    .read       = my_read,
    .release    = my_release,
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl,
};


/* INITIALISATION FUNCTION */
static int __init my_init(void)
{
    int i;
    int res;
    printk("\nI am in Init Function");
    /* DYNAMICALLY DEVICE NUMBER */
    res = alloc_chrdev_region(&device_num,minor,MAX_DEVICE,DRIVER_NAME);
    if(res<0)
    {
        printk("\nRegister Device Num generation failed");
        return -1;
    }
    major = MAJOR(device_num);

    my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE,DRIVER_NAME);
    if(my_class == NULL)
    {
        printk("\nClass creation failed");
        return -1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<MAX_DEVICE; i++)
    {
        device_num = MKDEV(major, minor + i);
        cdev_init(&devices[i].mycdev,&my_fops);     //registration of device
        cdev_add(&devices[i].mycdev,device_num,1);  //attachment of device

        /* CREATE DEVICE NODES IN /dev/ DIRECTORY */
        my_device = device_create(my_class,NULL,device_num,NULL,"sample_cdev%d",i);     
        if(my_device == NULL)
        {
            class_destroy(my_class);
            printk("\nDevice creation failed");
            return -1;
        }

        devices[i].minor_num = minor+i;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    int i;

    printk("\nI am in Exit Function");
    /* REMOVE DEVICES AND NODES */
    for(i=0; i<MAX_DEVICE; i++)
    {
        device_num = MKDEV(major, minor + i);
        cdev_del(&devices[i].mycdev);
        device_destroy(my_class, device_num);
    }

    /* DESTROY CLASS */
    class_destroy(my_class);

    /* UNREGISTER DEVICE WITH KERNEL */
    device_num = MKDEV(major, minor);
    unregister_chrdev_region(device_num, MAX_DEVICE);
}

/* DEVICE OPEN METHOD */
int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    my_privatedata *dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, my_privatedata, mycdev);
    filp->private_data = dev;
    dev->KERN_SIZE = 4096;
    printk("\nIn character driver open function device node %d", dev->minor_num);
    return 0;
}

/* DEVICE WRITE METHOD */
ssize_t my_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *usr_buff, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    my_privatedata *dev = filp->private_data;

    if(CIRC_SPACE(dev->KERN_BUFF.head, dev->KERN_BUFF.tail, dev->KERN_SIZE) >= 1)
    {
        int i;
        char ch;
        for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            get_user(ch, &usr_buff[i]);
            dev->KERN_BUFF.buf[dev->KERN_BUFF.head] = ch;
            printk("\nIn character driver write function and value of KERN_BUFF is: %s", dev->KERN_BUFF.buf);
            dev->KERN_BUFF.head = (dev->KERN_BUFF.head + 1) & (dev->KERN_SIZE-1);
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        printk("\nCopy from user to kernel space failed");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* DEVICE READ METHOD */
ssize_t my_read(struct file *filp, char __user *usr_buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    my_privatedata *dev = filp->private_data;
    int res;
    printk("\nI am in character driver read function");
    dev->KERN_BUFF.buf = "Bye Bye";
//  usr_buf = dev->KERN_BUFF.buf;

    res = copy_to_user((char *)usr_buf, (char *)dev->KERN_BUFF.buf, strlen(dev->KERN_BUFF.buf)+1);
    printk("\nData '%s' from kernel buffer to user buffer copied successfully with bytes: %d",dev->KERN_BUFF.buf,strlen(dev->KERN_BUFF.buf));

/*  if(res == 0)
    {
        printk("\nData '%s' from kernel buffer to user buffer copied successfully with bytes: %d",dev->KERN_BUFF.buf,strlen(dev->KERN_BUFF.buf));
        memset(dev->KERN_BUFF.buf, 0, strlen(dev->KERN_BUFF.buf));
        return strlen(dev->KERN_BUFF.buf);
    }
    else
    {
        printk("\nCopy from kernel to user failed");
        return -EFAULT;
    }
*/
    return 0;
}

/* DEVICE RELEASE METHOD */
int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    my_privatedata *dev = filp->private_data;
    printk("\nI am in release function and minor number is %d", dev->minor_num);
    return 0;
}

/* DRIVER IOCTL METHOD */
long my_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd,unsigned long arg)
{
    printk("\nIn Driver ioctl function");
    my_privatedata *dev = filp->private_data;

    switch (cmd)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                int count;
                count = CIRC_CNT(dev->KERN_BUFF.head, dev->KERN_BUFF.tail,dev->KERN_SIZE);
                printk("\nSize of buffer count is %d",count);
                return count;
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                int space;
                space = CIRC_SPACE(dev->KERN_BUFF.head, dev->KERN_BUFF.tail,dev->KERN_SIZE);
                printk("\nSize of buffer count is %d",space);
                return space;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                printk("\nNothing to show");
                break;
            }
    }
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

My user space writer app is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char Ubuff[50], Kbuff[50];

    fd = open("/dev/sample_cdev1", O_RDWR);
    if(fd < 0) {
        perror("Unable to open the device file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter a string");
    gets(Ubuff);

    /* Write the data into the device */
    write(fd , Ubuff , strlen(Ubuff) + 1);

    close(fd);  
    return 0;
}
```

My user space reader app is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char Ubuff[50], Kbuff[50];

    fd = open("/dev/sample_cdev1", O_RDWR);
    if(fd < 0) {
        perror("Unable to open the device file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Read the data back from the device */
    memset(Kbuff , 0 ,sizeof(Kbuff));
    read(fd , Kbuff , sizeof(Kbuff));
    printf("Data from kernel : %s\n", Kbuff);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

In my_write function I get a kernel null pointer dereferencing error at

```
            dev->KERN_BUFF.buf[dev->KERN_BUFF.head] = ch;
            printk("\nIn character driver write function and value of KERN_BUFF is: %s", dev->KERN_BUFF.buf);
            dev->KERN_BUFF.head = (dev->KERN_BUFF.head + 1) & (dev->KERN_SIZE-1);
```

`my_read` function doesn't seem correct but since I am unable to write something to kernel circular buffer, I am unable to test `my_read` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't checked the posted code.  However, the pipe already does this very kind of organization.   If it were me, I'd just use a pipe.

Comment: in the user space reader application, shouldn't the memset, read, printf sequence be in a loop and exit the loop when the read returned value (which currently is not being checked) indicates 0 bytes read or indicates an error?

Comment: 'gets' is depreciated and soon to be eliminated from C.  suggest using 'fgets' as then buffer overflows are easily avoided.

Comment: this line: 'dev->KERN_BUFF.buf = "Bye Bye";'  only copies a pointer.  suggest using: strnlen( dev->KERN_BUFF.buf, "Bye Bye", sizeof("Bye Bye")+1 );   // +1 so includes the '\0' string terminator byte.  Note: when ever copying into the buffer, always limit the number of characters copied to what room is currently available in the buffer.

Comment: But how to get rid of null pointer dereferencing error? I am not getting that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have not allocated any space in your circular buffer...`dev->KERN_BUFF.buf = kmalloc(...)`
Don't forget to free.
Also you are registering 2 my_private_data, that means every fd would get its own my_private_data. I think you want the producer and consumer to address the same data. maybe you'll need a spin_lock...

also read this: [CIRCULAR BUFFERS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/circular-buffers.txt)